# What is another way to say "allow(s) for a..."?

Tags: phrases, phrase-requests

For example:

> "To become a policeman, it's recommended you have a college degree,
>   which allows (or **would allow**) for further advancement in your
>   career."

I done some of my own research and came up with nothing.

Comment: You could use 'which is a stepping-stone to', or 'which facilitates' (far more formal).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Good choices.  Would "could furnish" work?

Comment: 'Could furnish/provide an opportunity for' are probably better. // But you need to show signs of (even unfruitful) research.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these verbs:

To [**permit**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/permit):

> to allow (something) to happen
>   to make something possible

or, although less strictly fitting "allow,"

to [**facilitate**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/facilitate):

> to make (something) easier
>   to help cause (something)

*Would permit* or *would facilitate* would work in the example, particularly if the audience does not already have a college degree, as implied by context.